# Set a string based on a prompt() value?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have the following snippet:

```
var max = prompt("");   
var selector = '#list > listitem > label[value=max]';
var node = document.querySelector(selector);
node.click();
```

I want to set the the `selector` string based on the input value of `max`.

Comment: So ? What is the question ? Do you mean `node.maxLength = max`

Comment: What does "set prompt value" mean? Also, [`value` is not a valid attribute for `label` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element), so the selector doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @jhonde: No, it isn't valid, see the link to the specification above. You might have it there, but that's not the same as it being valid.

Comment: @jhonde: What is that meant to say?

Comment: `node.value = max;`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to use the value of the `max` variable in the selector, use string concatenation (and put quotes around it):

```
var max = prompt("");   
var selector = '#list > listitem > label[value="' + max + '"]';
var node = document.querySelector(selector);
```

Two different things going on there:

1. We're using string concatenation to put the *value* of `max` into the string.
2. Completely unrelated to that, we're also putting that value in quotes in the selector so that spaces or some other characters don't blow up the selector. `[value=foo]` is a valid attribute matching selector, but `[value=foo bar]` is not. `[value="foo bar"]` is. While putting the value in quotes won't solve everything (notably, if a user types a `"`, you're in trouble), but it will at least handle spaces.

---

Or if you're using ES2015 (aka "ES6"), you could use a template string:

```
// ES2015 only!
var max = prompt("");   
var selector = `#list > listitem > label[value="${max}"]`;
var node = document.querySelector(selector);
```

---

Note, though, that `value` is [not a valid attribute for `label` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element). Form fields have `value`, not labels.

Comment: @jhonde: Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to do there.

Comment: @jhonde: What does "set output value" mean?

Comment: @jhonde: I'm sorry, you'll have to have a friend or colleague help you with your English. The question you actually asked has been answered. If you have a follow-up question, have a friend or colleague help you post a new question with the new information you need. Perfect English is **not** required, but we do need to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @jhonde: Again: The question you actually asked has been asnwered. If you have a *further* question, post it as a new question (with help from a friend or colleague, because again, what you're saying isn't clear).

Comment: @jhonde, It looks like you are trying to mix privileged Firefox add-on API's with ordinary (or even Greasemonkey) javascript.  You can't do that anyway close to what you have shown.  Open a new question. Follow T.J.Crowder's advice.